# How do I make this array flattening function behave recursively in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

This function will flatten an Array only two levels deep.

```
function arrFlattener(arr){
  var newarr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var target = arr[i];
      if(Array.isArray(target)){
        for(var j = 0; j < target.length; j++){
          if(Array.isArray(target[j])){
              for(var k = 0; k < target[j].length; k++){
                newarr.push(target[j][k]);
              }
          } else {
            newarr.push(target[j]);   
          }  
        }
      } else {
         newarr.push(arr[i]);
      }
   }
     return newarr;
}

arrFlattener([1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6],[7],[8]]]); // returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

Obviously a recursive function is what I need. In pseudo code I imagine a while loop which will run until it can't find a nested array in the current Array.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Think about what it means to be recursive and rework your code. If you get stuck somewhere, SO is here to help. As it stands, SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Cruiser Honestly I think I am stuck here — And it's not like I didn't present  any code at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the function right after the check for `isArray`, then just assign the concatinated result to `newarr`, because you expect possibly more than one element.

Basically you leave the next iteration to the function call instead of iterating the children array. This eliminates all other following loops (in the old function), because they are done in the function itself with one loop only and a recursive call, if necessary.

```js
function arrFlattener(arr) {
    var newarr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
            newarr = newarr.concat(arrFlattener(arr[i])); // get the result of the recusion
        } else {
            newarr.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return newarr;
}

console.log(arrFlattener([1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6], [7], [8]]])); // returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple ES6 solution would be something like

```
function flatten(arr) {
    const out = [];  // Stores the flattened output; modified by `walk`.
    function walk(arr) {
        arr.forEach((val) => {  // Iterate through `arr`;
            if(Array.isArray(val)) walk(val);  // if the value is an array, call `walk`,
            else out.push(val);  // and otherwise just push the value to `out`.
        });
    }
    walk(arr);
    return out;
}

console.log(flatten([1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6],[7],[8]]]));
```

The output is, as required,

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is based on a recursively working `Array.reduce` approach and does acknowledge `arguments` arrays too ...

```js
var array_flatten = (function (Array, Object) {

  "use strict";

  var
    array_prototype_slice = Array.prototype.slice,
    expose_internal_class = Object.prototype.toString,

    isArguments = function (type) {
      return !!type && (/^\[object\s+Arguments\]$/).test(expose_internal_class.call(type));
    },
    isArray     = ((typeof Array.isArray == "function") && Array.isArray) || function (type) {
      return !!type && (/^\[object\s+Array\]$/).test(expose_internal_class.call(type));
    },

    array_from  = ((typeof Array.from == "function") && Array.from) || function (listAlike) {
      return array_prototype_slice.call(listAlike);
    };

  return function flatten (list) {
    list = (isArguments(list) && array_from(list)) || list;

    if (isArray(list)) {
      list = list.reduce(function (collector, elm) {

        return collector.concat(flatten(elm));

      }, []);
    }
    return list;
  };

}(Array, Object));


console.log(array_flatten([1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6], [7], [8]]]));
```